# how to do post in nsurlconection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, post, nsurlconnection

http://[domain]/functionsdata.php?action=get_projectdetails
This is my url how to do post city and how to fetch data based on city key in nsurlconnection in objective c  ios?

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Comment: i havent experience on nsurlconnection.. havent do anything

Comment: First of all: `NSURLConnection` is deprecated, use `NSURLSession` instead. Second: Like, there is absolutely no other related question for that on StackOverFlow, or any tutorial in the whole Internet? So please, do some research, and come back with a specific issue in the code that you tried, by editing your question with theses new informations.

Comment: Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40913753/4370893 @Larme he might need to do it in macOS 10.8 or lower, and in that case `NSURLSession` is not available.

Comment: @vitormm It's tagged with iOS, so it's since iOS9 that's it's deprecated, and NSURLSession should be available though. Also, when questions are too broad like this, it shows lack of research, and I consider pointing out it's deprecated may be an help.

Comment: @Larme about the question being broad, yes, that's true. About using deprecated classes, yes, he should have pointed that if that's the case, but considering that the question was too broad that may be the case; since there aren't many details there is no way to know.

Comment: i am working on old project maintenance i dont want to rework entire thing thats why i am asking @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made that code for my own project, but it should suit for your problem as well. This is the needed code to use it. You can add it to two separated files or the same file that is going to use it.

```
@implementation NSString (VMMStringWebStructure)
-(NSString*)stringToWebStructure
{
    NSString* webString = [self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    webString = [webString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];
    webString = [webString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];
    webString = [webString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
    webString = [webString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];

    return webString;
}
@end

@implementation NSWebUtilities
+(NSString*)launchURL:(NSURL*)url withPostString:(NSString*)post
{
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (responseData.length > 0) return responseData;
    }
    else
    {
        if (error) return [error localizedDescription];
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Received invalid status code: %d.",nil),response.statusCode];
    }

    return nil;
}
+(NSString*)launchURL:(NSURL*)url withPostValues:(NSDictionary*)postDict
{
    NSArray* postKeys = postDict.allKeys;
    NSMutableArray* postLines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString* key in postKeys)
    {
        [postLines addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",key,[postDict[key] stringToWebStructure]]];
    }

    return [self launchURL:url withPostString:[postLines componentsJoinedByString:@"&"]];
}
@end
```

In your case, you could use it in that way:

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://[domain]/functionsdata.php?action=get_projectdetails";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSDictionary* postValues = @{@"city",@"<city name goes here>"};
NSString* output = [NSWebUtilities launchURL:url withPostValues:postValues];
```

That will retrieve the output has a `NSString` called `output`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * requestUrl = @"http://[domain]/functionsdata.php?action=get_projectdetails";

NSMutableRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: requestUrl]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSDictionary *requestParams = [@"city":@"value"];

NSData *jsonRequestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestParams options:kNilOptions error:&error];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonRequestData];

NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[myConnection start];
```

Comment: Thq let me check give some time @vitormm

Comment: @Ram Sagar did it, I just added his code to a code block ;P I will post my own answer soon